# Yii DatePicker CGridView date

Tags: php, jquery, yii, datepicker

I want to show the date that the user picked from the date picker inside the field of the search after searching and submitting by Ajax.

I used this

```
'afterAjaxUpdate' => 'reinstallDatePicker',
```

and

```
 Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('re-install-date-picker', "
   function reinstallDatePicker(id, data) {
       $('#created_at').datepicker();
    }
 ");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'test-master-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    'afterAjaxUpdate' => 'reInstallDatepicker',
    'filter'=>$model,
    'columns'=>array(
    array(
        array(
                'name'=>'event_master_end_date',
                'type'=>'raw',      
                'value'=>'($data->date == 0000-00-00) ? "Not Set" : date_format(new DateTime($data->date), "d-m-Y")',
               'filter' => $this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker', array(
                    'model' => $model, 
                    'attribute' => 'date',
                    'options'=>array(
                        'dateFormat'=>'dd-mm-yy',
                        'changeYear'=>'true',
                        'changeMonth'=>'true',
                        'showAnim' =>'slide',
                    ),
                    'htmlOptions'=>array(
                        'id'=>'date',
                    ),
                  ), 
            true),
        ),
    ),
)); 

Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('for-date-picker',"
function reInstallDatepicker(id, data){
       $('#date').datepicker({'dateFormat':'dd-mm-yy'});
    }
");
?>
```